# no se puede cambiar la fuente de letra en chorme?

Tags: html, css

en mi pagina quiero cambiar el h1 a otra fuente de letra intenete muchas veces en chrome y no me dejo lo cargue en firefox y se pudo alguien sabe por que como puedo hacer que cambie en todos los navegadores aqui si se ejecuta bien pero no en chrome

```css
h1{
    font-family:SF TransRobotics;

}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
       
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <section class="wrap">
         
               <h1 class="title">hola </h1>
         </header>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo SF Transbotic es una web font, primero debes descargar el archivo de la fuente, subirlo al servidor e incluirlo en tu hoja de estilos, así:

```
/* #### Generated By: http://www.cufonfonts.com #### */

@font-face {
font-family: 'SF TransRobotics';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('SF TransRobotics'), url('SF TransRobotics.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Fíjate en el parámetro url() que debe apuntar a la ruta donde subiste el archivo .woff que contiene la fuente.

Si ya has hecho esto ten en cuenta que debes colocar comillas simples al llamar a la fuente en el CSS, así:

```
h1{
    font-family:'SF TransRobotics';
}
```